# How to find the count of total connections in snowflakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We know that we have "show transactions" to see the transactions currently connected to database.
But I am interested
- To get the  count of active users for each warehouse?
-History of connections count for each warehouse?
Is there a way to get above information using the sql commands (not the web ui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to see the warehouse and active user mapping. There is no direct views as per my knowledge but you can leverage provided query where by keeping  warehouse size !='0' you can tied warehouse and user together. You can check the below link

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

**Before that**

- Snowflake Sessions are not tagged with user name or account , those are system 
  generated ID.
- User and warehouse relationship is zero or many (An active user can use multiple warehouse in parallel , also a warehouse can be used by multiple users at same point of time)
- A user can have active session without a running warehouse
- It is not mandatory to have an active user to keep your warehouse running
- Finally, queries can also be executed without turning the warehouse up

  ```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('minute', query_history.START_TIME ),'YYYY-MM-DD 
  HH24:MI') AS "query_history.start_time",
  query_history.WAREHOUSE_NAME  AS "query_history.warehouse_name",
  query_history.USER_NAME  AS "query_history.user_name"
  FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY  AS query_history
  WHERE (query_history.WAREHOUSE_SIZE != '0')
  GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('minute', query_history.START_TIME ),2,3
  ORDER BY 1 DESC
  ```

Note : Above SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY view refresh has latency of 45 minutes